HttpClient & dependency Injection
I have been reading a lot about socket exhaustion and DNS resolution issues while using HttpClient incorrectly. The recommended approach is to use a shared instance of HttpClient through dependency injection during the lifecyle of the application.
I have no issues with the basic dependency injection.
I have a base Class which initialises the Client with the relevant properties, this call is registered as a Singleton when the application loads (https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/3201)
     public class BaseNippyApiService : IBaseNippyApiService
    {
        public HttpClient Client { get; private set; }

        public BaseNippyApiService()
        {
            ResiliencePipeline<HttpResponseMessage> retryPipeline = new ResiliencePipelineBuilder<HttpResponseMessage>()
                .AddRetry(new MobileHttpRetryStrategyOptions())
                .Build();

#pragma warning disable EXTEXP0001
            ResilienceHandler resilienceHandler = new(retryPipeline)
            {
                InnerHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler(),
            };

            Client = new HttpClient()
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("REMOVED"),
                Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
            };
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", DeviceInfo.Platform.ToString());

            if (!SentrySdk.IsEnabled)
            {
                SentrySdk.Init(options =>
                {
                    options.Dsn = "REMOVED";
                });
            }
        }
    }

Registering the Singleton in Maui Program (code for this post is in a clean basic app for testing)
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });

#if DEBUG
            builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IBaseNippyApiService, BaseNippyApiService>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();

        return builder.Build();
    }
}

On the Main Page i can use constructor injection to obtain the Client, this is a crud example, im using VMs in the main app
  IBaseNippyApiService _NippyService;

public MainPage(IBaseNippyApiService bns)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _NippyService = bns;
}

Issue starts here. The first 2 lines are fine, I can use the service passed from the constructor on MainPage to access my other service methods. The problem lies in the 3rd line, in the object _NippyService is always null when passed to the object
AdCampaignService svc = new AdCampaignService(_NippyService);
 List<AdCampaign> campaigns = svc.GetAdCampaignsAsync(subAdminArea);           
 await campaigns[0].Delete();

I have methods within the AdCampaign class for Create, Update, Delete.
Ive tried passing in then interface through the constructor so I can set the AdCampaign Service constructor with the shared instance of httpClient, always null.
Ive also tried to get the registered service here too but that fails with target of invocations (Using IServiceProvider, registered by default in MAUI app)
     public AdCampaign(IBaseNippyApiService bns) 
 {
     if (_AdCampaignService == null)
         _AdCampaignService = new AdCampaignService(bns);
 }

   

I've tried a utility method found in the MAUI weather sample app to get the service
https://github.com/davidortinau/WeatherTwentyOne/blob/main/src/WeatherTwentyOne/Services/ServiceExtensions.cs (Recommended by Gerald Versluis (Microsoft))
    public async Task<CustomWebResponse> Delete()
{
    if(_AdCampaignService is null)
    {
        var service = DataService.Utility.ServiceProvider.GetService<IBaseNippyApiService>();
        _AdCampaignService = new AdCampaignService(service);
    }

    return await _AdCampaignService.DeleteAdCampaignAsync(this.Id);
}

I still have the ability to not call Create, Update & Delete on the object and call the service methods but pass the object to them i.e. AdCampaign.CreateAsync(adCampaign) but that doesn't sit well with me.
Is the approach wrong and I should be just call service methods outside of the object or should I be able to call methods of an object which calls a shared HttpClient instance?

I would suggest registering and injecting the HttpCLientFactory instead as that handles DNS and disposing for you, all you need to do is ask it for a client when you need one

The consensus is to not use HttpClientFactory which is detailed more here https://www.milanjovanovic.tech/blog/the-right-way-to-use-httpclient-in-dotnet.
I have resolved the issue and will be posting soon. There is an understanding to Dependency Injection needed to resolve the null issue i was having. Thanks for looking

oh, is that in the "The Smart Way To Create HttpClient Using IHttpClientFactory" section of that link?

@stuartd thanks for pointing that out, it's the wrong link. It affirms my point regarding limited information on the correct approach. Here is the correct link. Microsoft podcast says not to use the client factory, leads to socket expections https://doumer.me/improve-http-request-performance-in-dotnet-maui-xamarin/

first off, thanks for looking and i hope this answer helps those who come after me with the same issue. There is limited information on the internet, mainly due to which questions you will ask in order to find the answer. It takes understanding to ask the correct questions.
Recap
Each time i wanted to instantiate a service from inside and object the injected value was null. This is a misunderstanding in constructor injection.
     public AdCampaign(IBaseNippyApiService bns) 
 {
     if (_AdCampaignService == null)
         _AdCampaignService = new AdCampaignService(bns);
 }

Maui Program
Here is where you register those items you wish to be available for Constructor injection. Initially I thought you could use these everywhere which is true but you need to understand a little about dependency injection to how values are injected.
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IBaseNippyApiService, BaseNippyApiService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAdCampaignService, AdCampaignService>();

Both IBaseNippyApiService and IAdCampaignService are now available for injection via a constructor.
Important
If you instantiate an object, then constructor injection does not work because have manually performed the creation of the object. Dependency injection is not creating the object therefore no value is injected.
 AdCampaign campaign = new AdCampaign();

You will need to pass the expected constructor property in. This caused the confusion on my part and i started passing properties to the constructor from everywhere. Especially in test cases, worked but caused confusion and lead to getting stuck.
 BaseNippyApiService baseNippyApiService = new BaseNippyApiService();
 AdCampaignService serv = new AdCampaignService(baseNippyApiService);

Solution
I registered the AdCampaignService in MauiProgram making it available for injection.
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAdCampaignService, AdCampaignService>();

All Services registered in MauiProgram can be injected into your pages or view models via the constructor.
    IBaseNippyApiService _BaseNippyApiService;
    IAdCampaignService _AdCampaignService;

    public MainPage(IBaseNippyApiService baseNippyApiService, IAdCampaignService adCampaignService)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _BaseNippyApiService = baseNippyApiService;
        _AdCampaignService = adCampaignService;
    }

I can then call the service
  List<AdCampaign> campaigns = _AdCampaignService.GetAdCampaignsAsync(subAdminArea);
           

And inside the object (IAdCampaignService is registered in MauiPrograme, so value is injected)
   private IAdCampaignService _AdCampaignService { get; set; }

   public AdCampaign(IAdCampaignService adCampaignService) 
   {
       _AdCampaignService = adCampaignService;
   }
   public async Task<CustomWebResponse> Delete()
   {
       return await _AdCampaignService.DeleteAdCampaignAsync(this.Id);
   }

I was able to call .Delete() because _AdCampaignService is not null because the Constructor injection worked. I didnt create the object (no new keyword), a list was returned from a service call therefore Dependency Injection performed the Constructor injection, setting _AdCampaignService for me.
CustomWebResponse response = await campaigns[0].Delete();

I do have a .Create() method in AdCampaign, in this instance i would be instantiating the object and passing in the service
      AdCampaign adCampaign = new AdCampaign(_AdCampaignService)
  {
      Description = "Create with test case",
      ImageURL = "",
      B64Image = "",
      MimeType = ".jpg",
      ValidFrom = DateTime.Now,
      ValidTo = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30),
      SubAdminArea = "Derry and Strabane"
  };

   CustomWebResponse response = await adCampaign.Create()

